# Como desabilitar o content layout guide para utilizar scrollview - swift

Tags: swift

estou estudando por um curso da Alura e a versão do Xcode do meu professor é anterior a minha, minha versão 13.4 e a versão do professor é 10.1
Em uma determinada parte é preciso usar scrollview e desabilitar o content layout guide, só que a minha versão de Xcode não aparece a caixinha para desabilitar igual a do professor.
Alguém poderia me ajudar , por favor, sou iniciante em swift .

[Na tela do professor ao adicionar o scrollview e ir ate a aba "show the size inspector" aparece a caixinha de content layout, a versao dele é a 10.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wH0jb.jpg)

[Essa imagem é o print do meu xcode, a construção esta sendo por xib, não aparece no meu app a caixinha de content layout, lembrando que a minha versao do xcode é a 13.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOV7n.jpg)

[essa imagem representa como o meu professor faz a desabilitacao na versão dele, mas na minha não existe essa caixinha.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh6Xl.png)

Comment: Oi Ana, Bem vinda ao site. Para aumentar as chances de obter uma resposta, sugiro editar sua pergunta e colocar algumas informações, como por exemplo: 13.4 é a sua versão, certo? Saberia dizer qual é a do seu professor? Poderia colocar uma print mostrando aonde você está procurando esta propriedade? As vezes você está olhando no lugar errado. Já tentou fazer essa alteração por meio do código? Um abraço e boa sorte

Comment: Muito obrigada pelas dicas!! Vou fazer essas alterações agora! Por conta dessa configuração eu estou presa no andamento do app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa aba *Size inspector* (e outras, como a *Attributes inspector*) mostram as propriedades dependendo da classe que você selecionou. Isso inclui as classes superiores por meio de herança. Por exemplo, podemos ver na [documentação](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview) que a classe `UIScrollView` herda todas as propriedades da `UIView`:

`@MainActor class UIScrollView : UIView`

Essa aba mostra as propriedades de cada classe, em seções diferentes. Então no caso de uma `UIScrollView`, existem duas seções: `UIView`, e `UIScrollView`.

Pela sua segunda imagem da pergunta, podemos ver que a seção referente as propriedades da `UIScrollView` está escondida. Clique no botão <kbd>Show</kbd> para exibí-las:

[image: Localização do botão Show.]

Isso deve exibir as propriedades específicas da `UIScrollView`, que é onde a opção *Content Layout Guides* está e pode ser desabilitada igual o curso que seu professor mostrou.

Quando as opções estão exibidas, o botão <kbd>Show</kbd> é trocado para <kbd>Hide</kbd>, que agora serve para ocultar as propriedades.

Observação: Essa estrutura vale para mais de duas classes também. Por exemplo, a classe `UITableView` herda de `UIScrollView` que por sua vez herda de `UIView`. Quando selecionamos uma `UITableView`, nas abas de *attributes* e *size* podemos ver as propriedades das três classes:

[image: Aba com três seções]

Comment: Consegui! Muito obrigada!

Comment: @AnaPontes De nada! Se a resposta lhe agradou, não se esqueça de aceitá-la para ajudar futuras buscas no site. Você pode aceitá-la clicando no (✔️) ao lado da resposta escolhida.

Comment: Com certeza, voce é foda, obrigada !!! Eu tava a 4 dias parada no app por conta disso

Answer (score 0):

Para ter a opção de desabilitar o *Content Layout Guide* você precisa arrastar o `UIScrollView` para dentro da `UIView` principal, assim:

Ou seja, tanto o `UIView` quanto o `UIScrollView` devem estar dentro da mesma `UIView`.

Comment: Eu arrastei o scrollview para a uiview e alterei as constraints para 0, mas como esta habilitada essa opção de "content layout" o meu scrollview não aplicou as constraints que eu adicionei.